# System.out.println(4 | 3)

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(4 | 3);
```

The output is 7. It does addition up to 3 numbers, but how does this work? What is the syntax?

Comment: And each with its own illustration, haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binary OR

```
  3 = 011
  4 = 100
  ----------
3|4 = 111 = 7
```

It doesn't always mean addition

```
  2 = 10
  2 = 10
2|2 = 10 = 2
```

Answer (score 10):

That's because `|` is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

```
100    4
011    3
---
111    7
```

So the result is 7.

If you want more details on bitwise operators, read: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's doing a binary OR operation

```
0100    - this is a 4
0011    - this is a 3
 |
0111    - result is 7
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? What you *are* doing is a binary or of two numbers:

```
0b011 
 ||
0b100
 ==
0b111 -> 7.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(4 | 3);
```

Its a bitwise OR operator. Explanation  -

```
4->100
3->011
   ----
   111 ->7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 3 =  0011
 4 =  0100
 |_____|
    |
    V
   0111 
    |
    V
    7
```